# Can't access model method into celery task

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I have some issue with my Celery tasks. In my method I want to synchronize in background the soundcloud music library of the user

```
@task(name="synchronize_library")
def synchronize_library(user_id):
    from api.models import User

    logger.info("Enter in function")
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)

    attr = getattr(user, "has_soundcloud_account")
    logger.info(callable(attr))

    if user.has_soundcloud_account():
        logger.info("User has account")
        # Do some stuff
    else:
        logger.info("User has not account")
        # Do some stuff
```

When I call this method in a synchronous context like :

```
synchronize_library(1)
```

Everything works fine so there is no error in this method, but if I call :

```
synchronize_library.delay(1)
```

That's what I can see in the celery logger :

```
[2016-10-25 10:02:44,078: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: synchronize_library[3e8e8a67-c896-4d3e-96fe-0959abed749d]
[2016-10-25 10:02:44,081: INFO/Worker-1] synchronize_library[3e8e8a67-c896-4d3e-96fe-0959abed749d]: Enter in function
[2016-10-25 10:02:44,744: INFO/Worker-1] synchronize_library[3e8e8a67-c896-4d3e-96fe-0959abed749d]: True
```

So I have an object with a method `has_soundcloud_account` but the process seems to stop when I decide to call this function.

After few tests this behaviour appears every time I try to call a method of my model.

Any idea of what's going on?

EDIT : This is the code of my method `has_soundcloud_account()` :

```
def has_soundcloud_account(self):
        return self.settings.soundcloud_access_token is not None
```

Comment: How do you check for the soundcloud account ? Celery workers have a limitation in which they can't fork new processes, (see https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1709), So it's good to provide the code for your sync_lib method.

Comment: I added the code of my method has_soundcloud_account() , I don't think that is the problem because it's simply check a boolean variable.